# HTML - Is it necessary to enclose a call to the css file into quotes?

Tags: html, css, double-quotes

I have a .html file and ist .css file. I call the .css trough the instruction

```
<link rel= stylesheet href= mystyle.css>
```

But if I use

```
<link rel= "stylesheet" href= "mystyle.css">
```

then nothing changes in my page. Is there some difference between using the quotes or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the spec defines it to have quotes, but some browsers go beyond and will know what you meant.

**EDIT**: I was wrong! From the spec

> Attributes are placed inside the start tag, and consist of a name and a value, separated by an "=" character. The attribute value can remain unquoted if it doesn't contain space characters or any of " ' ` = < or >. Otherwise, it has to be quoted using either single or double quotes. The value, along with the "=" character, can be omitted altogether if the value is the empty string.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values

Comment: This depends on HTML version. XHTML requires quotation marks around all attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

In **HTML5** you don't need to use quotes for any attributes. But, sometimes you have to because of knowing where a string ends. In **HTML4.1** and **XHTML** you have to use quotes.

It's a good practice to use quotes anyway, even if you don't need them.