# Wrong colors in <hr>

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, colors, rule

Today I discovered this by accident:

```
<hr width=100% color=red />
```

creates a red horizontal rule, but

```
<hr width=100% color=red/>
```

creates a green horizontal rule.

This isn't just with the color `red`, if there is a `/` directly behind the color name, another color will be drawn. This doesn't work for color codes like `#000000` (to `#000000/`).

Just of curiosity, **here is my question**: *How does the color get chosen? Is this a bug or intended?*

---

Additional info:

Browser: Google Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m

Installed plugins / add ons: Ad Block Plus

I tested this with IE 10 and it has the same problem as Chrome.

Comment: You're already operating outside of well-specced behavior by not enclosing attribute values in quotes...

Comment: Notably, your slashes are the wrong way for close tags `<tag />`

Comment: You guys probably didn't understood the question

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318911/why-does-html-think-chucknorris-is-a-color

Comment: @Russel Zahniser: No, you don't have to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112126/html-is-it-necessary-to-enclose-a-call-to-the-css-file-into-quotes

Comment: The same thing happens when correct (forward) slashes are used.

Comment: @James Webster: Changed it, the problem is the same though.

Comment: @Mr.Alien We understand the question just fine. Essentially: "Why does a weird thing happen when I write invalid HTML?" `red\\` is undefined; the browser isn't required to do anything in particular. It's probably  a quirk of Chrome's color parsing, and could change in the next version for all we know.

There's no "why" that doesn't involve a code review of Chromium source.

Comment: @PaulRoub: Well, tried the same code with IE 10 just know. Same thing happens.

Comment: @PaulRoub I know why this happens, the first 2 comments thought that it was a syntax error, but the thing is op did that deliberately, that was my point :)

Comment: @Frithjof Refer Musas comment

Comment: The answer is a combination of @Musa 's comment and the fact (as linked to by OP) that quotes aren't required around a value _if_ that value has no spaces or other enclosing characters, so without a space the slash is considered part of the value (`red/`) — it will also be green if the value `"red/"` is in quotes.

Comment: Though, again thanks to @Musa 's comment, I believe the recommended value for red in this case should be `ChuckNorris` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8DmJ/)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, somewhat surprisingly, intentional error handling, described in clause [2.4.6 Colors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#colors) of HTML5 CR. It is presumably meant to maintain compatibility with legacy content that has weirdly broken color designators that have been traditionally processed in a certain manner by browsers.

When the mixed-syntax (partly HTML, partly XHTML) markup `<hr width=100% color=red/>` is used, in a document served as text/html (when served with an XHTML content type, it would simply cause nothing but an error message to be shown), the `color` attribute will be parsed as `red/` (with the slash as part of the value). Since this does not match any color name, rules for parsing a legacy color value will be applied.

This means that any character that is not a hexadecimal digit is replaced by the digit 0, and if the resulting value is not six characters long, trailing zeroes will be added. Finally, the value is prefixed with `#`, so it will be interpreted as a hexadecimal color designator. Thus, `red/` yields `#0ed000`, which is the light green color that you see.

Similarly, `<hr width=100% color=blue/>` would cause the color `#b00e00` to be used.

The problem can of course be avoided by using either HTML syntax (which has no `/` before `>`) or XHTML syntax (which has quotation marks around each attribute value).

Answer (score 1):

The semantic analizer of your browser detect the `<hr>` tag and later try to determinate the atributes for that label.

Using white spaces as token separator, your first line have 3 attributes (noted that the correct slash for finish a tag in html is / ). In this case, the second token `color=red` as interpreted as a attribute (color) and value (red). In your second line there are only 2 attributes. The second attribute (color) has the value `red\` that is not a valid identifier in the asociative array for colors.

#### Why your browser return blue?

Each browser manage the exceptions that diferents ways, its problably that your browser return the first value in the asociative array colors.

I should recommend to you that use quotes as delimiter for attributes values.

Answer (score 0):

- I just tried it,and it works.
- First I copy your code and execute, it was unexpected. Still I try same code, and I just put " " (double quotes) around the color name, and tried color codes too.
- and I found, it is working properly with Crome,IE and Mozilla.

Answer (score -1):

using the color attribute might be the problem. Try border-color.

```
<hr width="100%" style="border-color:#f00">
```

Comment: well, this doesn't answer but anyways upvoted as the attribute he is using is now deprecated

Comment: @Mr.Alien It seems `color` attrubute is not deprecated.. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr).

Comment: @Mr_Green non standard